# Is it possible to import different producer library transitive dependencies based on consumer java version in Gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I have a `producer` Java library written in Java 6. It is consumed in several projects and the problem is some packages from Java 6 are missing in Java 11 so if the `consumer` project is in Java 11 I have to manually attach those missing packages (their alternatives) in its `gradle.build`. Is there a way to somehow specify in the producer library so that if the consumer's Java version is 11, those additional dependencies are imported?